# "In doing so" grammar

Tags: grammar, difference, usage

Is "in doing so" a fixed phrase or can it be changed? Are any of the following sentences possible?

- You shouldn't need to have killed that person while being in that time, because of doing so you changed the present.
- You shouldn't need to have killed that person while being in that time, doing so you changed the present.
- You shouldn't need to have killed that person while being in that time, upon doing so you changed the present.
- You shouldn't need to have killed that person while being in that time, with doing so you changed the present.

Comment: Technically, none of those is a correct sentence, nor would they be correct with "in doing so", because they're [comma splices](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/engagement/2/1/34/).  You can't just ram together two sentences without a conjunction or at least a semicolon.  Some of them would be correct if you just put "because" in between the two parts.

Comment: Yes, "doing so" can take various prepositions like in, upon, on, while, before, after, etc.   Also "by" but not "with".  If standing alone, it usually *implies* a preposition like "by".  However as stangdon points out your examples are not grammatically correct since you need to connect them as you would separate sentences, with a conjunction or appropriate punctuation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you mean when you ask whether "in doing so" is a fixed phrase or can be changed.  However, while none of your examples above are totally correct sentences, here's a correct alternative:

> You shouldn't have killed that person while in that time; in doing so, you changed the present.

It can also be two sentences.

> You shouldn't have killed that person while in that time.  In doing so, you changed the present.